# Prevent surgical mask from riding up

Tags: clothing, health

Due to covid I'm now required to wear a surgical facemask in communal areas for work. The one we have look like this:

[image: image of surgical facemask]

I have the problem that the mask often rides up until it nearly covers my eyes and I have to touch it frequently to pull it back down over my chin.

Are there any lifehacks to prevent the mask from riding up?

Comment: In your photo, you show the outside of mask-the side facing away from you. When you wear the mask, the folds should face up on your side - the other side (in your photo) should face you when it is worn according to plan. Pinch the metal strip to close the gap on either side of your nostrils snugly. Does this help?

Comment: Not a hack, but I just bought masks that fit me on my own dollar.  These ears-as-hooks ones are horrid, hurt, make me look like I have wings, and worst of all interfere with my glasses.   (comment because not an answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick that works for me is to cross the loops on the sides, so the elastic from the top to go around the bottom of the ear and then from the top of your ear to the bottom of the mask.

Most people will do it on both ears, but if your head is quite unevenly shaped it might be needed to do it only on one side.

When masks came use here I noticed people wearing masks like that and I was forever fighting my mask going into my eyes and just tried it, it was the right solution for me.
And it does not cost anything and you can easily do it with all new masks without having to work on them.

Comment: When you do that, don't forget to tuck the loose sides inside the mask to close the gap created on each side. Here's the video that shows how:<br> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3Y26UGulrI

Comment: In the video they use an other method as I do not tie a knot in the elastic bands. It does look good though.

Comment: Yes, I did not intend to contradict or diminish your hack. I was commenting on the gap that is created in both instances due to the rectangular shape of the mask. The hack you and the link both also solve is how to better fit the "one-size-fits-all" to a narrow jawline or a small face. Good Stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to find the best position for the ear loops of the mask to best fit your face shape.

Sew a couple of buttons onto a headband positioned for the best fit.
[image: Headband ear saver]

Your ears will thank you. Call it an earsaver.
You certainly want to use it to relieve the pressure from double masking (now the recommended procedure).

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

When and if this happens using a simple procedure mask as shown, best practices now recommend that you double mask yourself. In practice, the second mask helps prevent masks from moving around on your face.

For the optimal technique, please search online for a tutorial. Check the date of the tutorial to ensure it is current. Check the comments for possible errors and omissions.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try a [**mask brace**](https://www.designboom.com/design/former-apple-engineers-seal-your-surgical-mask-05-29-2020/) to hold your mask in place.

One is easy to make from a few elastic bands.
In addition, it will help close any gaps around the mask that make them inefficient or even ineffective.

[image]

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Tips for mask wearing:
I use breathe right strips on my nose to help breathe better and keep my mask from riding up with  Velcro Dots  one on the breathe right strip other on inside of mask. Or double sided sticky tape.
I also chew mint gum to prevent dry mouth ,lip balm keep my lips from being dry. I use anti-fog spray on my glasses.